# Add certificate as trust on android in command line (adb)

Tags: android, proxy, android-emulator, certificate, x509

I have a project where I need to script some actions on the android emulator but I got a problem for add a Burp certificate, to attach a proxy to my emulator.

When I add a certificate thanks to this script:

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -in cacert.der -out cacert.pem
hash=$(openssl x509 -inform PEM -subject_hash_old -in cacert.pem | head -n -1)
mv cacert.pem $hash.0
adb.shell("mount -o rw,remount,rw /system")
adb.push("$hash.0", "/system/etc/security/cacerts/$hash.0")
adb.shell("chmod 644 /system/etc/security/cacerts/$hash.0")
adb.shell("mount -o ro,remount,ro /system")
```

It works I can intercept the traffic, but I have a warning for each interception as it follow:

[image]
[image]

I know that I should added this cerificate as trust. I know how to do it with the graphical interface but I want to find a way to do it in command line with adb.

Thanks